# OPTION request rejected by CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Since last week I have been struggling to fix this problem but still its not resolved. I have deployed my Django code on AWS lambda and configure the API gateway to serve all api and admin section.

All http method are working fine from rest client/postman but when I am trying to integrating the api in AngularJS then try to perform the POST request to the api but Chrome sends a default OPTION request to the server but every time CloudFront returns an error with 500 status.

***"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."***

[image]

[image]
Please help me to resolve the issue as I need to move my product to production.

Thanks,
AbdulWahid

Comment: Have you [read the API Gateway documentation for CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Michael-sqlbot's comment, I finally succeed to get 200 response from AWS Lambda. Just enable CORS for your Method in API Gateway then it will work.

Comment: I was using Zappa for server less hosting so in my case it was an issue with zappa configuration. I have disabled the cors layer on api gateway and handle it on application layer which I have uploaded on aws lambda.